# Can't change String to Integer because negative sign follows number

Tags: java, string, integer

I am using Java to read in a CSV file and do some data analysis with the items given. A couple of the data points that I read in are a bunch of different numbers that can range from -999 to 999. I want to compare these numbers to each other so I start by turning the String into an Integer.
The problem I get is that the CSV file saves negative numbers with the negative sign following the number (1-). This throws a NullFormatException. I feel like there is an easy way around this that I'm overlooking. Any help would be great.

Say random data is {1,19-,20-,7,8} I need {1,-19,-20,7,8}

```
int[] nnaOH = new int[x];
int[] nwOH = new int[x];
int[] nuaOH = new int[x];
for (int z = 1; z < x; z++){
    nnaOH[z] = Integer.parseInt(naOH[z]);
    nwOH[z] = Integer.parseInt(wOH[z]);
    nuaOH[z] = Integer.parseInt(uaOH[z]);
    }
```

Comment: `String#endsWith("-")`  helps ?

Comment: ^ This. But you should rather try to fix your input files....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to parse your integers with a custom format:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class DecimalFormatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#;#-");
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("123-").intValue());
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("321").intValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-123
321
```

Comment: I think your answer is better than mine (and the other person's), because you're not doing any string manipulation or changing the input at all.  This is the way to go, OP.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  It will detect the hyphen at the end and remove it before parsing the number, setting it to a negative value.

```
private int parseInt(String str) {

    if (str.endsWith("-")) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        return -Integer.parseInt(str);
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```